# A simpler version of "the likes thereof"

Tags: phrases, expressions, phrase-requests

What's a simpler version of "the likes thereof"? (Meaning: things that are similar to it.)

e.g. in the following sentence:

> I find SomePopularBook and the likes thereof interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest revision would be

> I find *Mermaid on a Pogo Stick* and **the like** interesting.

While syntactically possible, the expression **the likes thereof** is very rare in English usage.  A quick [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%22%20the%20likes%20thereof%22%2C%22the%20likes%22%2C%22the%20like%22%2C%22ilk%22&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%22%20the%20likes%20%22%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%22%20the%20like%20%22%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%22%20ilk%20%22%3B%2Cc0) check on **the like** vs. **the likes** shows that while neither is what you would want to call prevalent usage, the plural noun usage of **likes** in this context is minimal to nonexistant.  Adding **thereof** to **likes** produces no matches at all.

**The like** is an idiomatically acceptable synonym for "**similar things**, and may be related in ordinary use (if not in etymology) to the expression **the ilk**, which Wiktionary (and the ilk) defines as

*In modern use, ilk is used in phrases such as of his ilk, of that ilk, to mean ‘type’ or ‘sort.’ The use arose out of a misunderstanding of the earlier, Scottish use in the phrase of that ilk, where it means ‘of the same name or place.’ For this reason, some traditionalists regard the modern use as incorrect. It is, however, the only common current use and is now part of standard English.*

All that being said, I would *not* recommend the answer offering **"similar objects**" any more than I would endorse "**similar things**," since these both focus the speaker's interest on the book as a kind of object, rather than on the marvelous work of literature that it contains.